# Jquery Smooth Scrolling within page when one of hyperlink is clicked

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, scroll, jsfiddle, vertical-scrolling

I have hyperlinks on my page.Using Anchor links, I can make the page scroll towards the anchor and guide the users towards the different sections within page.I am following example on fiddle something like  http://www.position-relative.net/creation/anchor

I have added Jquery standard library and jquery code as explained on fiddle.but i am unable to get desired result does i need to include other plugins for implementing this functionality.Fiddle is as below

Second question is does it possible to download complete source code including html,css,jquery in form of zip from fiddle

```
 <script>
        $(".scroll").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //calculate destination place
            var dest = 0;
            if ($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
            } else {
                dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
            }
            //go to destination
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: dest }, 1000, 'swing');
        })
</script>
<nav>
    <a class="scroll" href="#destination1">Destination 1</a>
    <a class="scroll" href="#destination2">Destination 2</a>
    <a class="scroll" href="#destination3">Destination 3</a>
    <a class="scroll" href="#destination4">Destination 4</a>
</nav>
<section id="destination1">
    <h1>Block 1</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </p>
    <h1>Block 2</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
    </p>
    <h1>Block 3</h1>
    <p>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <h1>Block 4</h1>
    <p>
        Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.
    </p>
    <p>
        Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </p>
</section>
```

Comment: can you post your fiddle here

Comment: I have edited and added fiddle in that